# How can I play a video in the background, and play other content in front of it?

Tags: c#, video, xna, sprite

I am stuck in drawing textures in XNA, this is the code in the draw method :

```
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture, screen1, null, Color.White, 0, nuller, None, 1);
            spriteBatch.Draw(bird1, birdbox1, null, Color.White, 0, nuller, None, 0);
            spriteBatch.End()
            }
```

So I basically want to put the videoTexture, which is already loaded with a video in the back, and the birdbox1 rectangle in front of the video. But this code does not help me do that, can anyone help me out?

Forgot to mention, nuller = (0,0) 2d vector.

Comment: That looks like it should work... What exactly *is* it doing?

Comment: The bird1 texture isn't drawn. The videotexture simply plays and overlays everything, I'm almost losing my mind out of frustration here, this is the only thing left in my game and it just won't work.

Comment: And I presume it *does* draw if you comment out the video? Did you try setting their layer numbers the same (it shouldn't matter since you already have the right draw order)?

Comment: Okay, I did it, I had a stupid mistake with videoTexture being stuck in another loop, this code had nothing wrong with it, I apologize!

Comment: No problem, happy to be a rubber duck for you :)